# Parsing to package-independent Tex

Tags: pandoc, mathjax, mhchem, portability

Is the ability to create package-independent TeX readily available?  I would like, for example, to have a system with access to a package (e.g. mhchem) create TeX that could then render on a system without access to that package.

Here's the context: pandoc does not parse \ce{} when reading MathJax, so I would like to find/create a filter that converts \ce{} to something that pandoc will accept.  Presently, I type chemical equations manually (`$2H_2 + O_2 \rightarrow 2 H_2O$`) and would prefer to be able to write `$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$` and pass the file through a filter prior to rendering with pandoc.

Given that I have been unable to find a solution already floating around the web, I suspect I am asking for something that is currently a hard problem to solve.

Comment: MathJaX simply isn't TeX: any commands have to be implemented in JavaScript

Comment: as @JosephWright says someone would have to write mhchem in javascript rather than tex, but fortunately [that has been done](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/mhchem.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reference @DavidCarlisle - I can do some digging from there.

Comment: An mhchem-to-LaTeX parser is available in JavaScript [Github](https://github.com/mhchem/mhchemParser). There is also a [discussion](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6668) how this could be used for Pandoc.

Comment: Thanks @mhchem, that discussion is what led me to ask this question.  I'm guessing, to your knowledge no one has advanced the issue beyond what was covered in that github thread?

Comment: @bobthechemist Correct, I don't know of any other works or discussions.